# recursion reverse lines of a file not working for me

Tags: java, file, recursion

I Just want to reverse the lines of a file but I cannot figure it out. I thought I'd use recursion as the easiest way but it's not working. here's what I've figured I'd do.

```
public void reverseLines(Scanner s, String outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
    String st = s.nextLine();
    if(s.hasNextLine()){
        reverseLines(s, outputFile);
    }
    pw.println(st);
    pw.close();     
}
```

I'm using this file:
hello there
this ones the middle
this ones on top

And I keep getting this:
hello there
   middle

and I am just so confused. I've seen this question asked before but all the questions are "how do I reverse these lines" and the answers are "use recursion" but still sorry for asking

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: changed it to fix the file problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File f = new File("D:\\test.txt");

    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("D:\\test2.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        reverseLines(s,pw);
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void reverseLines(Scanner s, PrintWriter pw) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String st = s.nextLine();
    if(s.hasNextLine()){
        reverseLines(s,pw);
    }
    pw.println(st);
    System.out.println(st);  
}
```

Original file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

This is console output:

```
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

You need to handle the file outside the recursive function otherwise you'll close it before it finishes

Comment: Oh shoot, it was called printLines in my code but I changed it here to make it more readable and forgot to change both I'm mostly just confused why it prints the first line and the last word of the middle line and nothing else

Comment: You can test recursion in your browser console with two simple commands. 

Something like `x = function(y) { if(y>0) {x(y-1);} console.log(y); }` and then run it with `x(10);`

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about all the debugging methods thanks! This recursion just kind of caught me off guard because I feel like I can easily do harder recursive problems then this, because I have in the past for assignments

Comment: See the update. I tested a code similar to yours without any issue

Comment: Yeah I know I've done that it just makes me more confused! I don't want to just print the lines to the console though I want them in a new file :(

Comment: Wow thanks! I guess I just had to pass a printwriter instead of the file name which makes way more sense I don't know why I wasn't doing that from the begining